# Buk uploading Error using Nodejs & Angular 6?

Tags: node.js, angular, angular6

I have a code where I need to upload bulk records like (50,000) from an CSV. From angular 6, we are making an restapi call from where we are passing the formdata to node server. In node portion we are looping that set of records(50,000) and we are uploading it in to our backend by splitting it like 1500. Records will be uploaded for every consecutive 1500.

So In our local it is working completely fine & we have tested uploading same 50000 records. But we have moved the same code to our SIT environment where we are facing the error. After uploading certain amount of record (20000 records), again its starts uploading from first record. This is some weird behaviour, which we couldnt test it in local. Can anyone please please suggest What I need to do?

```
var bulkUploadData = async function (jsonblob, res) {
  var payloadjson = [];
  var jsonResponse = {};

    try {

          for (let i = 0; i < jsonblob.length; i++) { 
           if(jsonblob[i].PN != null){
         var JFB = {}
             var arrayy = [];
         if (jsonblob[i].Otyp != "L") {
            JFB.srv = jsonblob[i].SA;
            JFB.ptype = jsonblob[i].PTy;
            JFB.ms = jsonblob[i].PN;

                var a = JSON.stringify(JFB)
            payloadjson.push(a);

           }
         else {
            JFB.ms = jsonblob[i].PN
            JFB.srv = jsonblob[i].SA;
            JFB.ptype = jsonblob[i].PTy;

            var a = JSON.stringify(JFB)
            payloadjson.push(a);

            }

        if ((payloadjson.length % 1500) == 0) {

                console.log("Inside first loop---------counter---------  ", i );            
                var result = await update.invokeSDK("fnname", payloadjson, res)

                payloadjson = [];
                await sleepTime(20)
                console.log("-----sleeped for 20ms----- ",i)
            }

            if (jsonblob.length == i + 1 && payloadjson.length > 0) {
            var result = await update.invokeSDK("fnname", payloadjson, res)
                payloadjson = [];
            }

        }
        console.log("FRKNG Length _________i:  ",i);
        }

        jsonResponse = { "failedRecords": "fail" }
        return jsonResponse;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('error:----', err);
        return err;
    }
```

}